# jQuery format time returned from Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to format the time given by Google Maps API in their 'duration' to something I can actually work with.

When I return the duration, I get something like:

```
1 day 13 hours
2 days 22 hours
1 hour 12 mins
3 hours 18 mins
1 hour
6 mins
```

The only thing I can say for the way the duration is formatted is that it never shows more than 2 sets of numbers.  It doesn't (as far as I've seen) show days, hours and minutes, but that is the format I'm getting back.

I'd like to be able to take those numbers, turn them into seconds and do math from there (rounding hours, minutes, etc.)

How can I format those into something like total seconds?

**EDIT**
I am using the [Google Maps `DirectionRequest` service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests)

Comment: From the documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixResponses) I see that they return a numeric value with the text. Maybe you can be more specific on what API you are using.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex, Thank you for pointing that out.  I've updated my question

Comment: same thing: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Legs .Duration is an object containing value and text.

Comment: @SideriteZackwehdex, Thank you, I guess I didn't pay attention to the value and understand what it actually meant.  I need to RTFM a little more closely.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#DistanceMatrixResponses), it appears that the API returns both a "value" and a text amount:

```
}, {
  "status": "OK",
  "duration": {
    "value": 24487,
    "text": "6 heures 48 minutes"
  },
  "distance": {
    "value": 129324,
    "text": "129 km"
  }
```

The value for duration appears to be seconds, which might be easier to work with than the text value.

Comment: Ah, David, thank you - I will test this right now.  I just wrote a script to handle this thing, but I will look into that right now.

Comment: Thank you - I will accept your answer when the time limit expires!

Answer (score 0):

David784 has answered my question in the best possible way.

For anyone who still has a problem with this type of formatting, I've written this

**I HAVE NOT TESTED EXTENSIVELY**

```
function humanTimeToSeconds(time){
    var time_seconds = 0;
    time = time.split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < time.length; i++){
        if(i%2 == 0){
            var time_amount = time[i];
            var time_type = time[i+1];
            if(time_type == "days" || time_type == "day"){
                time_seconds = time_seconds + (time_amount * 24 * 60 * 60); 
            } else if(time_type == "hours" || time_type == "hour"){
                time_seconds = time_seconds + (time_amount * 60 * 60);  
            } else if(time_type == "mins" || time_type == "min"){
                time_seconds = time_seconds + (time_amount * 60);   
            }
        }
    }
    return time_seconds;
}
```